# Conjure-up and Kubernetes, how do I connect?

Tags: aws, conjure-up, kubernetes

Afternoon all!

I just did a build and deploy and everything seems to be running great in AWS. I wanted to login to the nodes via ssh but noticed there are no pem keys associated tot eh nodes. Is there something in the deploy configuration I might have missed or are these nodes simply not meant to be logged into?

Cheers,
-Stephen

Answer (score 2):

Conjure-up uses the [modeling software Juju](https://jujucharms.com/) under the covers, which includes the ability to ssh into machines it deploys.

I just tried this here on a xenial system.

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
conjure-up
```

After deploying CDK with conjure-up to the substrate of your choosing, you should be able to use `juju` to list and connected to the nodes it deployed.  Some helpful commands below.

- `juju models`
- `juju status`
- `juju ssh 4`       # connect to machine 4
- `juju ssh etcd/0`  # connect to etcd unit 0